# How to make subtitle by default in a certain position in mpv

Tags: configuration, mpv, video-subtitles

This is my mpv.conf -

```
$ cat ~/.config/mpv/mpv.conf
alang=eng,en,english
slang=en,eng, english
sub-scale=1.00
save-position-on-quit
```

Now I want that the subtitle should appear at a certain place while playing the media file. I'm sure this is configurable.

Answer (score 3):

As long as that "certain place" isn't the very bottom of the screen, mpv's manual page mentions the `--sub-pos` argument as the way of setting it, at least vertically [`sub-pos` without the '--' for use in mpv.conf]:

```
--sub-pos=<0-150>
   Specify the position of subtitles on the screen.  The  value  is
          the vertical position of the subtitle in % of the screen height.
          100 is the original position, which is often  not  the  absolute
          bottom  of  the  screen, but with some margin between the bottom
          and the subtitle. Values above 100  move  the  subtitle  further
          down.

             Warning

                    Text  subtitles (as opposed to image subtitles) may be
                    cut off if the value of the option is above 100.  This
                    is a libass restriction. This  affects  ASS  subtitles
                    as well, and may lead to incorrect subtitle rendering 
                    in addition to the  problem above.

                    Using --sub-margin-y can achieve this in a better way.
```